# Class Crashed in JavaScript in Particle function

Tags: javascript

Hello I have java Script code was working but it crash in line 44 it says:

> 437anxious.html:44 Uncaught ReferenceError: Particle is not defined
>       at animate (anxious.html:44)

And I think the problem in my class I am thinking it is going to work like java but it is not so could someone please let me know how I am going to fix it ><

Here is my code:

```js
<html>

<head>
    <title>Anxious</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-content: center;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="toto.js"></script>
    <script>
        var canvas;
        var ctx;
        var particles = [];
        var particleIndex = 0;
        var particleNum = 15;
        //jquery init
        $(document).ready(function() {
            canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
            setInterval(animate, 30);
        });

        function animate() {
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            this.x = canvas.width / 2;
            this.y = canvas.height / 2;
            this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
            this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
            this.gravity = 0.3;
            particleIndex++;
            particles[particleIndex] = this;
            this.id = particleIndex;
            this.life = 0;
            this.maxLife = Math.random() * 30 + 60;
            this.color = "hsla(" + parseInt(Math.random() * 360, 10) + ",90%,60%,0.5";
            Particle.prototype.draw = function() {
                this.x += this.vx;
                this.y += this.vy;
                if (Math.random() < 0.1) {
                    this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
                    this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
                }
                this.life++;
                if (this.life >= this.maxLife) {
                    delete particles[this.id];
                }
                ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
                //c.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 5, 10);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, 2.5, degToRad(0), degToRad(360));
                ctx.fill();
            
            setInterval(function() {
                //normal setting before drawing over canvas w/ black background
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
                    new Particle();
                }
                // c.globalCompositeOperation = "darken";
                for (var i in particles) {
                    particles[i].draw();
                }
            });
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>

</html>
```

and here is my library:

```js
      function degToRad(deg) {
            var radians = (deg * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2;
            return radians;
        }

        function getRandom(min, max) {
            return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
        }

        /**
         * Returns a random integer between min (inclusive) and max (inclusive)
         * Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
         */
        function getRandomInt(min, max) {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        }
```

Comment: Your for loop here isn't doing anything: `for (var i = 0; i < particleNum; i++) {
                    new Particle();
                }` the `new Particle();` isn't being set to a variable.

Comment: Where is the `Particle` class defined ?

Comment: So what do you expect `Particle` to be? You *do* not define it anywhere.

Comment: By "*here is my library*" you mean the `toto.js` file?

Comment: Yes the toto.js is the library that but it isn't used for this project but i have to include it in my project

Comment: The problem is when you placed the code in the library it worked fine and the particle is define but when i tried to make it the way i did it the particle is not defined ?! so wired i know ><